# Calling index of an array in loop causing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

So I basically import a JSON file. I get back many arrays and each array has 4 elements in it. I want to parse the 3rd element from each array into it's own variable array.

```
$("#nextQ").click(function() {

  var Quotes = [];
  var totalQ //The total number of available quotes to choose from

  //Get quotes from JSON file
  $.ajax({
    url: '../facts.json',
    datatype: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data[0][2]); //This WORKS
      console.log(data.length); //Returns 64

      totalQ = data.length;

      for (i = 0; i <= totalQ; i++) {
        Quotes[i] = data[3][2]; //This WORKS
        Quotes[i] = data[i][2]; //This gives ERROR

      }
    }
  });

});
```

When I use `data[i][2]` I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined`. However this error doesn't occur if I use `data[6][2]` or any other number.

Comment: `i <= totalQ;` to `i <totalQ;`

Comment: Thanks, any idea why that would give me an error on the 2nd index and not the 64th?

Comment: Or more jQuery'ish -> `$.each(data, function() {...`

Comment: @Badrush - the first index in an array is zero, yet `length` really starts at one, as the length would be `1` if the array had one item, but that item would be at `array[0]`. When you loop, you loop to `array.length - 1`, but you're looping until `i` is the same as the length, so you're trying to look up `array[length]`, which doesn't exists

Comment: @Badrush , `data[data.length]` will be undefined, you are trying to get the property of `undefined`. The property you are trying to access is `2` which is `undefinded`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the `for` loop condition from `i <= totalQ;` to `i <totalQ;` , since index starts from `0`

```
for (i = 0; i < totalQ; i++) {
    Quotes[i] = data[i][2]; 
}
```

Or you can use `$.each()` as @adeneo suggested

```
$.each(data,function(i,v){
  Quotes[i] = v[2]; 
})
```

Or you can use native javascript `map()`

```
Quotes = data.map(function(v){
  return v[2]; 
})
```

Comment: Thanks man, this worked. I would have caught this if the error hadn't told me the issue was with the 2nd index (random???)

Comment: @Badrush , `data[data.length]` will be undefined, you are trying to get the property of `undefined`